# How to call a function only once every X time in an infinite loop in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, while-loop, multiprocessing, infinite-loop

I have a Python program with many functions that I call inside a while loop.

I need my while loop to call all the functions the first time it does the loop, but then I would want to call one of those functions only once every two minutes.

Here is a code example:

```
def dostuff():
    print('I\'m doing stuff!')
def dosthings():
    print('I\'m doing things!')
def dosomething():
    print('I\'m doing something!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        dostuff()
        print('I did stuff')
        dosthings()
        print('I did things')  #this should run once every X seconds, not on all loops
        dosomething()
        print('I did something')
```

How can I achieve this result? Have I to use multithreading/multiprocessing?

Comment: *to call all the functions the first time it does the loop* - you don't need to put those in infinite loop in such case

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: 3.7
Yes, I need to put functions in infinite loop in my program. Those are example functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick-and-dirty single threaded demo, using [`time.perf_counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter), you can alternatively use [`time.process_time()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.process_time) if you don't want to include time spent in sleep:

```
import time


# Changed the quoting to be cleaner.
def dostuff():
    print("I'm doing stuff!")

def dosthings():
    print("I'm doing things!")

def dosomething():
    print("I'm doing something!")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = 5
    clock = -x  # So that (time.perf_counter() >= clock + x) on the first round

    while True:
        dostuff()
        print('I did stuff')

        if time.perf_counter() >= clock + x:
            # Runs once every `x` seconds.
            dosthings()
            print('I did things')
            clock = time.perf_counter()

        dosomething()
        print('I did something')

        time.sleep(1)  # Just to see the execution clearly.
```

[**See it live**](https://onlinegdb.com/HyrlyJpGS)

Comment: Works perfectly :) Thank you very much, I was stuck on this since a while

Comment: @kalikantus Glad to help! Feel free to [mark the answer as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/510616) if you feel like it was helpful :)